# Why cannot infer types of delegate parameters?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I can write this:

```
new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart((x) =>  //**parameter type not specified explicitly**
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(x); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
})).Start(5);
```

I can write this:

```
new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(delegate(object x) //**parameter type specified explicitly**
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(x); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
})).Start(5);
```

But I cannot write this:

```
30    new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(delegate(x) //**parameter type not specified explicitly**
31    {
32        for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(x); j++)
33        {
34            Console.WriteLine(j);
35        }
36    })).Start(5);
```

It gives multiple errors:

- The type or namespace name 'x' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) - line 30
- The name 'x' does not exist in the current context - line 32
- Identifier expected - line 30

Why delegates cannot infer parameter types? Language design decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although they're similar, anonymous delegates are not the same as lambda expressions, and they follow different rules. Parameter types in lambda expressions can be inferred implicitly, but anonymous delegates require you to specify the type explicitly.

And yes, it's a language design decision. Lambda expressions were introduced to support Linq, and requiring the explicit declaration of parameter types would have made the syntax less convenient.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to define anonymous methods.And this is one of them:

```
delegate(object x)
{

}
```

When you using this syntax you have to specify parameter type.delegates cannot infer parameter types and the reason is as you said language design decision.And it is about syntax.Also when you use lambda syntax:

```
(x) =>  {  ... }
```

Compiler creating a delegate type and a method behind the scenes.

Note: Maybe this answer doesn't contain enough explanation but you can take a look [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47887/C-Delegates-Anonymous-Methods-and-Lambda-Expressio) article to understand the difference